# Run time is too long. How to shorten run time for this function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory-leaks

We are designing a .ppm image editor app, but I keep getting an error with my load function where it just frees memory for a very long time. It eventually finishes but it takes a matter of minutes. I have included the code for the function and the messages from the Android Monitor.

```
private int height;
private int width;
private static int maxColorValue = 255;
private static Pixel image[][];

public void load(BufferedReader bufferedReader)
{
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(bufferedReader);
    //fin = new Scanner(new File(inFile));
    fin.useDelimiter("(\\s+)(#[^\\n]*\\n)?(\\s*)|(#[^\\n]*\\n)(\\s*)");
    // skips the P3 at the begging of ppm file
    fin.next();

    // get width and height
    width = fin.nextInt();
    height = fin.nextInt();
    // get max color value (255)
    maxColorValue = fin.nextInt();

    image = new Pixel[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int red = fin.nextInt();
            int green = fin.nextInt();
            int blue = fin.nextInt();
            Pixel newPix = new Pixel(red, green, blue);
            image[i][j] = newPix;
            //image[i][j].red = red;
            //image[i][j].green = green;
            //image[i][j].blue = blue;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Below is the error message only it repeats indefinitely.

```
09-02 17:07:11.276 28598-28602/edu.byu.cs.imageeditor D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 653K, 17% free 4721K/5668K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 28ms
```

Comment: Why is `image` static?

Comment: It wasn't but I was just trying everything and figured I'd give it a try. It didn't change anything.

Comment: It turns out that Android Studio just struggles with Strings and Scanners. So I just changed the code to use StringBuilder where I could and just used the bufferedReader and got it working.

Comment: In other words the problem was elsewhere. There are no Strings or Scanners in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Android Studio just struggles with Strings and Scanners. So I just changed the code to use StringBuilder where I could and just used the bufferedReader and got it working